# capture the Outlook 2013 Send event

Tags: c#, vsto

I'm working on an application that should capture the Outlook 2013 Send event. I have used a C# project to do the required task.

In particular I have used following code to do this task

```
public Outlook.Application OutlookApplication;
public Outlook.Inspectors OutlookInspectors;
public Outlook.Inspector OutlookInspector;
public Outlook.MailItem OutlookMailItem;
public delegate void ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(object Item, ref bool Cancel);

applicationObject = application;
addInInstance = addInInst;
OutlookApplication = application as Outlook.Application;
OutlookInspectors = OutlookApplication.Inspectors;
OutlookInspectors.NewInspector += new InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(OutlookInspectors_NewInspector);
OutlookApplication.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(OutlookMailItem_Send);

string strchkTo = OutlookMailItem.To;
string strchk = "hello Welcome to c#";

OutlookInspector = (Outlook.Inspector)Inspector;
if (Inspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.MailItem)
{
   OutlookMailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)Inspector.CurrentItem;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following steps works fine at my side.

1. Create a Shared Add In. Choose Outlook to be the supported Application.
2. In the Application Property page, set Outlook to be the start up program.
3. Add a reference to Microsoft Outlook 11.0 Object Library.
4. Import the namespace:

   using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

5.Replace the original system generated fields:

```
private object applicationObject;
private object addInInstance;
```

with the following new fields: (No ItemSend event)

```
public Outlook.Application OutlookApplication;
public Outlook.Inspectors OutlookInspectors;
public Outlook.Inspector OutlookInspector;
public Outlook.MailItem OutlookMailItem;
```

6.In the OnConnection method, replace all the system generated codes with the following ones:

```
OutlookApplication = application as Outlook.Application;
OutlookInspectors = OutlookApplication.Inspectors;
OutlookInspectors.NewInspector += new   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(OutlookInspectors_NewInspector);
        OutlookApplication.ItemSend +=new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(OutlookApplication_ItemSend);
```

7.Add the event handler function OutlookInspectors_NewInspector:

```
 void OutlookInspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
  {
     OutlookInspector = (Outlook.Inspector)Inspector;
     if (Inspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.MailItem)
     {
                OutlookMailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)Inspector.CurrentItem;
     }

  }
```

8.Add the event handler function OutlookApplication_ItemSend:

```
 void OutlookApplication_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
 {
   string strchkTo = OutlookMailItem.To;
   string strchk = "hello Welcome to c#";
   MessageBox.Show(strchk + "\r\n" + strchkTo);
}
```

Comment: What is the use of `OutlookInspectors_NewInspector` here? My code is working fine without handling event `NewInspector`, just by handling event `ItemSend`, and using `object Item` from parameter to get the MailItem.