# OutLook MailItem send event doesn't work

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, mailitem

I generate a message and open it for the user, using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. When a user sends the message in Outlook I want to capture this event. Not as discussed in this SO tread:

[capture the Outlook 2013 Send event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628357/capture-the-outlook-2013-send-event)

where I capture all sent emails, not only generated.

```
public static MailItem CreateMail() 
{
    Application outlook = new Application();
    MailItem mailItem = outlook.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
    // set recipients, body, ect..
    mailItem.Send += MailItemSendedHandler;
    Inspector inspector = mailItem.GetInspector;
    inspector.Activate();
    return mailItem;
}

static void MailItemSendedHandler(ref bool isSended) 
{
}
```

MailItem has a `Send()` method and a `Send` Event.  When I subscribe I get the error:

> Cannot assign to "Send", because it is a method group.

How can I capture the  `Send` event for my MailItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MailItem` is an interface which inherits from interfaces `_MailItem` and `ItemEvents_10_Event`. Both of them have `Send`. (In _MailItem it is a method, in ItemEvents_10_Events it is an event). I think we have a conflict, and need to clearly define which `Send` we want to use.

```
((ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Send += new ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler(MailItemSendedHandler);

static void MailItemSendedHandler(ref bool isSended) 
{
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation