# Is there any way for Visual Studio Team Services to track email communication on a bug between developer and user?

Tags: azure-devops

We are looking at moving to VSTS from Fogbugz/Kiln for item tracking and source control.

The one issue that I don't see parity in VSTS is that today with Fogbugz, our users can email foo@bar.com and it creates a work item in our system.  Then from that point, whoever is working on that bug can reply *from within the system* and the system sends the email and the correspondence is tracked along with the work item.  If the user replies, because the subject has "Item:1234" it knows to add the new email to the correspondence for Item 1234, not to create a new work item.

In looking online, it seems most people talk about addins that allow for creating a work item from Outlook, which is quite different from having the system manage the back-and-forth with the user, and allow the user to update the item just by replying to an email.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this, or an addon/extension that would support this functionality in VSTS?

Comment: Requests for tool recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported for VSTS, also there isn’t add-in or extension support this.

You can create an [outlook add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) to capture [ItemSend event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628357/capture-the-outlook-2013-send-event) and Get/Create/Update/Delete a work item by using VSTS [Work Items REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items).