# How to change Subject line on send if Ribbon checkbox is checked

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I'm working on an add-in that should allow me to select a Toggle Button or checkbox.

When the user clicks the Send button, I would like for the words "Secure" to be appended to the Subject line.

I was able to get this to work to where clicking on the Toggle Button will put the "Secure" word in the subject line without sending, but I do not want the user to remove the word from the Subject line, hence me wanting that to be done on Send event.

How can I get this to work? I have a Ribbon1.cs and ThisAddin.cs.

My first try was to have ThisAddin_ItemSend event in ThisAddin.cs set the subject line with an If statement checking if toggleButton1 is checked, but it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

When you are processing the button event, set a variable. Use its value when processing the Send event.

Keep in mind that since multiple inspectors can be displayed at the same time, the data and the event processing must be done on the per-inspector basis.

Comment: I believe i found one of my issues, I set break points on the ItemSend event and it is never triggered when sending.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, my understanding is that you want to add security words when the send event starts.I don't know if my understanding is correct.

My suggest is：

There are two kind of Send - the event and method. To distinguish them you need to cast the MailItem object to the [ItemEvents_10_Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=outlook-pia) interface：

```
((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Send += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler(MySendEventHandler);
```

You could refer to the link below:

[capture the Outlook Send event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628357/capture-the-outlook-2013-send-event)

[Set event handler for MailItem.Send in Outlook Addin](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b37fee0-dbcb-4494-8475-b2fc6b2ade2f/set-event-handler-for-mailitemsend-in-outlook-addin?forum=vsto)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a shot.

Comment: @BeeezLooking forward to your results